# How to fix Exception in Application constructor

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new in Javafx, I just downloaded JDK 12 and followed a tuturial, it has worked but not worked for me, (I'm using module to require javafx.controls)
here is the code: 
in my main class :

I tried a lot of solutions in SOFlow but no result, I tried :
1) add public keyword to my class
2) removed the main method
still not work help ?

```
package com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApp extends Application {


      public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(args);
        }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {



    }


}
```

and here is the error after executing it :

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx.HelloApp
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:890)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx.HelloApp (in module com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx) because module com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx does not export com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx to module javafx.graphics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:376)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:639)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:802)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Answer (score 5):

The solution is almost mentioned in the stacktrace; the issue is narrowed down to the point where it tells you about the export that is missing:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx.HelloApp (in module com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx) because module com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx does not export com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx to module javafx.graphics
...
```

Add the following line to the `com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx` module:

```
module com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx {
    ...
    exports com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx;
}
```

Or alternatively granting access to only a single module:

```
module com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx {
    ...
    exports com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx to javafx.graphics;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error like that because you haven't invoked anything inside the start method. You will have to set the `Scene` and also provide the directory of your `FXML` file.

I have corrected your code.

```
package com.teachersdunet.hellojavafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
       try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("directory_of_your_fxml_file"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
       } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       } 
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
                launch(args);
   }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: helps only in showing anything, provided s/he's using a fxml and a suitable controller. Does _not_ solve the error which is thrown due to incorrect project setup see [Fabian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57173052/203657) for a fix. Minor nit-pick: strictly speaking, the parameter of class.getResource is a package name (either absolute or relatively resolved) not a directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your class in default package org.example ,or you can add in module-info.java file(under package org.example) this line
exports(name of your created package).