# Exception when running first JavaFX modular program

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, module

I haven't much experience with java, however after reading another few threads I think I have an issue with how my program is set up, however can't seem to solve it. Basically I have a simple JavaFX program as follows.

```
package systemApp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SystemTestGUI extends Application{

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage){

                
    // create a new scene and add it to the stage         
    Scene scene = new Scene(null);         
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);         
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test Title");        
    primaryStage.show();   
    
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)     
  {         
    launch(args);     
  }

}
```

Initially I was getting unable to access errors on the javafx imports, having only worked with non-modular projects and javaFX, I did some reading and added the required into my module-info.java file. now this looks like this:

```
module System {
  requires javafx.graphics;
}
```

However when i try to run the program i get the following stack trace which I'm not fully confident reading:

```
    Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class systemApp.SystemTestGUI
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:890)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class systemApp.SystemTestGUI (in module System) because module System does not export systemApp to module javafx.graphics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:802)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
```

After reading this thread:
[How to fix Exception in Application constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166325/how-to-fix-exception-in-application-constructor/57176410)

I added this line to my module-info.java:

```
exports com.systemApp.SystemTestGUI to javafx.graphics;
```

However I get the following error on hover:

```
The package com.systemApp.SystemTestGUI does not exist or is empty
```

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong. My understanding of packages and modules is limited, so I may be doing something silly so any direction would be great.

Comment: you have to export your own package, here that is systemApp (which is violating java naming conventions, btw: no upper case letters in package names) - maybe time for working through a tutorial on modules :) Also, the package name you show in the [mcve] is different from the package name you added to the module-info.

Comment: After reading your comment I changed exports `com.systemApp.SystemTestGUI to javafx.graphics;` to `exports systemApp;` and it worked. I was being stupid but thank you genuinely because it was stressing me out. You have made my Sunday. I will change the package name also. :)

Comment: glad I could help :) Just to clarify: usually, you want to make your custom package available for all, which would mean removing the _to javafx.graphics_